# Original French phrasing of “The more fools the merrier”

Tags: expressions, proverbes

In English we have the phrase “*The more the merrier*”, meaning the more people there are the more festive and enjoyable that a situation will be.

I've seen in, translation, that French has a *similar* phrase: *The more fools the merrier*.

What's the original French of “*The more fools the merrier*”?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Plus on est de fous, plus on rit.](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/plus_on_est_de_fous,_plus_on_rit)

Comment: Anecdotiquement, difficile de ne pas citer également la subversion (de Coluche si je ne m'abuse ?) *Plus on est de fous, moins y'a de riz.*

Answer (score 3):

The more the merrier / Plus on est de fous, plus on rit

so for the more fools the merrier = Plus on est de fous, plus on rit

sources : http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Liste_de_proverbes_anglais_et_fran%C3%A7ais_%C3%A9quivalents

Answer (score 0):

Personnellement je préfère la forme française suivante de « The more fools the merrier » ;

- Plus on est de fous plus on s'amuse.

Comment: Le proverbe c'est « plus on est de fous, plus on rit ». De même qu'en anglais c'est _the more the merrier_, pas _the more fools, the happier_, ou _the more fools, the more the laughter_. Le proverbe en français apparaît dans des textes il y a 400 ans ! Ta préférence anglicise le proverbe sans raison.